# A problem of the definition of relative homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is a lemma on the textbook *algebraic topology a first course* (Greenberg).
I supposed that they are equal, not isomorphism.

Proof:$$H_q(X,A)\cong Z_q(X,A)/B_q(X,A)$$
I am wondering $Z_q(X,A)$ is a subgroup of $S_q(X)$ or the kernel of a homomorphism induced by the boundary operator. Actually, both of two are right.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: The homology group is defined as the quotient of the kernel of a boundary operator $\partial_q$ by the image of the preceding one $\partial_{n+1}$. So, yes, the isomorphism is an equality.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Is this from the first isomorphism theorem? They are equal in the iso sense. I don't know how to prove it though it is extremely obvious.

Comment: @StefanHamcke thanks( •̀∀•́ )

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with isomorphism theorems. The homology group $H_q(X)$ is simply defined as the quotient $Z_q(X)/B_q(X)$. The same is true for the relative homology group $H_q(X,A)=Z_q(X,A)/B_q(X,A)$. There is nothing to prove here. Note that one may also consider absolute homology as relative homology by taking $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: The group $Z_q(X,A)$ is a subgroup of $C_q(X,A)=C_q(X)/C_q(A)$, namely the kernel of the map
$$
\frac{C_q(X)}{C_q(A)} \to \frac{C_{q-1}(X)}{C_{q-1}(A)}
$$
induced by the boundary operator.

Comment: The note by Prof. J. Michael Boardman help a lot since I never read something like this before. http://www.math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/relhgy.pdf